# change the background color of Activity Node GOJS

Tags: gojs

I would like to change the background color of a particular node after the diagram has been loaded on click   event of button.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is a data Binding on the Shape.fill property of the object whose color you want to change, you can just change the property on the node data object by calling Model.setDataProperty. This is discussed in the section about "Changing Data Values" in http://gojs.net/latest/intro/dataBinding.html .

For more examples, search for "setDataProperty".